# Activate Cube with Compiz Manager/ Workplace problems

Tags: unity, xubuntu, compiz, workspaces, cube

I am trying to get the cube Compiz to work with workspaces on Xubuntu 14.4.  I tried to do a script with the terminal and failed.  Now my bar on my top screen will not retract and I can no longer do Ctrl+Alt Arrow keys to cycle from one workplace to another.  Any advice on fixing both these issues?